# Running a macro through multiple files

Tags: vba, excel

I've got a folder with ~300-600 files (depends on month), with various names.

I want to run a macro in each file, without opening them separately. Is that possible ?

Below is the macro I want to run. It does work when I open the files one by one, but with so many of them, I would like to cut some time.

```
Sub Przeroby()

Dim wbk1 As Workbook
Dim wbk2 As Workbook
Dim y As Variant
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LA As Integer
Dim Z As Variant

Set wbk1 = ActiveWorkbook
Set wbk2 = Workbooks.Open("U:\ZBROJARNIA\_WSPOLNE\Przeroby-podsumowanie.xlsx")
wbk1.Activate

Set sht = wbk2.Sheets(1)

y = sht.Columns("A").Find("", sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A"), xlValues, xlWhole, , xlNext).Row
x = Application.Sheets.Count

 LA = 2

Do While LA < x

Z = wbk1.Sheets(LA).Range("D12").Formula
sht.Cells(y, 1).Formula = Z

Z = wbk1.Sheets(LA).Range("N12").Formula
sht.Cells(y, 2).Formula = Z

Z = wbk1.Sheets(LA).Range("D14").Formula
sht.Cells(y, 3).Formula = Z

Z = wbk1.Sheets(LA).Range("D11").Formula
sht.Cells(y, 4).Formula = Z

Z = wbk1.Sheets(LA).Range("D10").Formula
sht.Cells(y, 6).Formula = Z

Z = wbk1.Sheets(LA).Range("U60").Value
sht.Cells(y, 8).Formula = Z

Z = wbk1.Sheets(LA).Range("U59").Value
sht.Cells(y, 9).Formula = Z

Z = wbk1.Sheets(LA).Range("U58").Value
sht.Cells(y, 10).Formula = Z

Z = wbk1.Sheets(LA).Range("U57").Value
sht.Cells(y, 11).Formula = Z

Z = wbk1.Sheets(LA).Range("U56").Value
sht.Cells(y, 12).Formula = Z

Z = wbk1.Sheets(LA).Range("U55").Value
sht.Cells(y, 13).Formula = Z

Z = wbk1.Sheets(LA).Range("U54").Value
sht.Cells(y, 14).Formula = Z

Z = wbk1.Sheets(LA).Range("U53").Value
sht.Cells(y, 15).Formula = Z

Z = wbk1.Sheets(LA).Range("U54").Value
sht.Cells(y, 16).Formula = Z

Z = wbk1.Sheets(LA).Range("U53").Value
sht.Cells(y, 17).Formula = Z

Z = wbk1.Sheets(LA).Range("U52").Value
sht.Cells(y, 18).Formula = Z

Z = wbk1.Sheets(LA).Range("U51").Value
sht.Cells(y, 19).Formula = Z


LA = LA + 1
y = y + 1
Range("U49:U60").Copy


Loop

wbk2.Save
wbk2.Close


End Sub
```

I know it's not perfect, but it gets the job done. Also, any tips with the above will be appreciated.

Edit: The target directory is on another computer, to which I connect via internal network. 
File with sorted data is on yet another network drive.

Comment: No, it is not possible without opening them.

Comment: Thanks everyone, found a piece code that allows to choose a folder from which I'm getting files. Now I'm getting a problem with file names, but it shouldn't be too hard to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create small .vbs file which you can run (by double click) and it will run your macro automatically on all your files in a specified folder.

First of all export your working macro to some location. And then copy paste below lines in a text file and save it as .vbs file.

```
Dim objFSO, objStartFolder, objFolder, colFiles, filePath
Dim xlApp, xlBook

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
objStartFolder = "Your folder path"

Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(objStartFolder)
Set colFiles = objFolder.Files
For Each objFile in colFiles
    filePath = objStartFolder & "\" & objFile.Name

    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    xlApp.Visible = False

    Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(filePath)
    xlApp.VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents.Import "Path to your .bas file"
    xlApp.Run "Name of your Sub"
    xlBook.Save
    xlBook.Close
    xlApp.Quit
Next

Set colFiles = Nothing : Set objFolder = Nothing : Set objFSO = Nothing
Set xlBook = Nothing : Set xlApp = Nothing : Set fso = Nothing
```

Just change the path in the file.

Comment: Getting an error quite often.
Unknown error while executing.
Row 17, symbol 5 (translating to english so it may not be accurate).
I could have made an error somewhere in directory paths. 

I Made 3 changes to the above:
`objStartFolder = "\\192.168.0.70\Betstal\WZ\2015\08.sierpień"
xlApp.VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents.Import "C:\Users\rzakrzewski\Documents\Module2.bas"
    xlApp.Run "Przeroby"`

Maybe "" are wrong ?

Comment: Got it working via someother means.
But I could still use the above for running the script from outside excel window. I tried deleting all parts regarding to obj, cold and filePath, but I can't get it working (Basically removing the need to move through different files).

Comment: The changes you've mentioned in your first comment is exactly what you have make. You have to make those changes and that's the reason, I've kept the file path and name like that. Let me know if you are still facing issues.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a vbs file you could also create an Excel Addin. This addin can contain the macro that you need to run for every workbook. Workbooks do need to be opened to execute the macro, but they can be opened (and later closed) without them being visible. I would also advise you to set any Workbook objects you create to nothing when you are finished with them. (Set wbk = Nothing)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Dir() function in VBA to get a list of all the files in a particular directory. Then it's just a matter of looping through each of the files to open, run macro, save, and then close.

Here is some code:

```
sPath = "U:\ZBROJARNIA\_WSPOLNE\"
sFile = Dir(sPath)
Do While sFile <> ""
  sFilePath = sPath + sFile
  Set wkBk = Workbook.Open(sFilePath)

  sName = sFile + "!Przeroby"
  Application.Run sName

  wkBk.Save
  wkBk.Close
  sFile = Dir()
Loop
```